# Find particular integral of $ (D^2+9)y=x\sin 3x$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My attempt:

$PI=x\frac{1}{D^2+9}(\sin 3x) - \frac{2D}{(D^2+9)^2}(\sin 3x) $

$= -\frac{x^2}{6}(\cos 3x) - \frac{6}{(D^2+9)^2}(\cos 3x)$

$= -\frac{x^2}{6}(\cos 3x) - \frac{1}{(D^2+9)}(x\sin 3x)$

Now, the second term is the one in the question, from where I actually started. At this point, I am a little lost.

My questions are:

1. Have I solved it correctly till now? If I have, how do I proceed forward? If I haven't, what's the correct way?
2. Will there be a difference if I change the order in which I operate over the $D$ terms in the Numerator and Denominator? Will the answer be different in both approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(D^2+9)y=x\sin 3x$$
$$y_p=x\dfrac 1{(D^2+9)}\sin 3x-\dfrac {2D}{(D^2+9)^2}\sin 3x$$
Now
$$\dfrac 1 {D^2+9} \sin 3x=\Im\dfrac {xe^{3ix}}{6i}=-\dfrac {x}{6}\cos (3x)$$
$$\dfrac 1 {D^2+9} \cos 3x=\Re\dfrac {xe^{3ix}}{6i}=\dfrac {x}{6}\sin (3x)$$

So that
$$y_p=x\dfrac 1{(D^2+9)}\sin 3x+\dfrac {2D}{(D^2+9)}\dfrac {x}{6}\cos (3x)$$
$$y_p=-x^2\dfrac {\cos 3x}6+\dfrac 13\dfrac {1}{(D^2+9)}(\cos (3x)-3x\sin 3x)$$
$$\dfrac 2{(D^2+9)}x\sin 3x=-x^2\dfrac {\cos 3x}6+\dfrac {x\sin 3x}{18}$$
$$\boxed {\implies y_p=-\dfrac {x^2\cos 3x}{12}+\dfrac {x\sin 3x}{36}}$$

---

*Now, the second term is the one in the question, from where I actually started. At this point, I am a little lost.*

When you have;
$$y_p= \text{Something}-y_p$$
Then you deduce that:
$$ 2y_p= \text{Something}$$
$$\implies y_p=\dfrac { \text{Something}}2$$

---

*Will there be a difference if I change the order in which I operate over the D terms in the Numerator and Denominator? Will the answer be different in both approaches?*

Yes operators are not COMMUTATIVE when applied to variables coefficients and functions so respect the order. Otherwise you will end with an incomplete particular solution. So the order should be for the second term:
$$\dfrac 1 {D^2+9}2D\dfrac 1{D^2+9}\sin(3x)$$

Comment: While I agree with what you say, but if I operate the Numerator D first(like I did in question), I will never get 2 terms, there. For example, from my solution in the question itself, it can be concluded that $PI=-\frac{x^2}{12} \cos 3x$ only, which is wrong. So is there any rule of thumb here?

Comment: You have to respect the order of operators since when you apply operators on functions it's not commutative. What you get is not wrong it's incomplete but ,not wrong. I hope this answer your question. @gemspark

Comment: Can you tell what is the order of operators here? Because I am under the assumption both D in Numerator and Denominator have the same order. Is it Denominator(Dr) first and then Numerator(Nr)? But then you did Dr->Nr->Dr.

Comment: I added some lines hope it's more clear now @gemspark

Comment: For the formula you used ? $\dfrac 1 {f(D)}. D'. \dfrac 1 {f(D)} h(x)$ in this oreder @gemspark Like i did in my answer So it should be $\dfrac 1 {D^2+9}2D\dfrac 1{D^2+9}h(x)$ I hope this helps

Comment: Is there any universal rule for order of any general $\frac{g(D)}{f(D)} $?

Comment: Not that I know @gemspark

Comment: If there any place else other than $\frac{-f'(D)}{f(d)^2}$, where I need to account for this order?

Comment: Well order of operators always matters with non constant coefficients. It's not commutative you can't change the order. That's why you get different answers when you chage the order. @gemspark

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{xe^{3ix}}{D^{2}+9}$$
$$=e^{3ix}\frac{1}{(D+3i)^{2}+9} (x)$$
$$=e^{3ix}\frac{1}{6iD(1+\frac{D}{6i})} (x) $$
$$=e^{3ix} \frac{1}{6i} (\frac{1}{D}-\frac{1}{6i}+\frac{D}{(6i)^2}-\cdot\cdot\cdot)(x)$$
$$=e^{3ix}\frac{1}{6i} (\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x}{6i}+\frac{1}{(6i)^2})$$

Just take the imaginary part as $P.I.$

Answer (score 0):

As the characteristic polynomial has the roots $\pm3i$, a particular solution needs to be the product of $e^{3ix}$ of a polynomial one degree higher than in the RHS.

$$f(x)=(ax^2+bx)e^{3ix}.$$

When plugged in the equation, this gives

$$(12iax+6ib)-x+2a=0$$ or $$a=-\frac1{12},b=\frac i{36}.$$